# Remove nesting from ModelSerializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to add routes to GET and PUT the status of a ticket.

```
class ReturnLabelTicket(models.Model):
   status = models.CharField(choices=...)

class ReturnLabelTicketStatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer of a return label ticket status."""

    status = serializers.ChoiceField(ReturnLabelTicket.StatusChoice.choices)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        """Take the whole data value as the status."""

        return super().to_internal_value({'status': data})

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        """Return the status string."""

        return instance.status

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """Update the ticket status."""

        instance.status = validated_data.get('status', instance.status)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = ReturnLabelTicket
        fields = ['status']
```

By default this serializer expects the JSON to be of the form `{ 'status': '...' }`, but I want to remove the status key and use the value directly. My `to_internal_value` works fine, but when I remove the nested status in `to_representation` I end up with an error at

```
ticketing-service    |   File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 549, in data
ticketing-service    |     return ReturnDict(ret, serializer=self)
ticketing-service    |   File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/serializer_helpers.py", line 18, in __init__
ticketing-service    |     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
ticketing-service    | ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

This is the relevant section of my `ReturnLabelTicketViewSet`.

```
    @action(
        detail=True,
        url_path='status',
        serializer_class=ReturnLabelTicketStatusSerializer
    )
    def status(self, _request, ticket_id=None):
        """Retrieve the ticket status."""

        ticket = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(ticket)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: I don't know if you know this already but `to_representation` should return a `dict`.

Comment: @VishalSingh Ok, but given my model serializer with a `status` field, how can I extract the value?

Comment: try calling super like this `data = super(ReturnLabelTicketStatusSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)` and see if you can extract what you want from data.

Comment: I need to return a single string, not a dict.

Comment: DRF Serializers are designed for django ORM which means that it manipulates django models and primitive dictionaries. I prefer you to bypass this behaviour directly in `status` action. You can leave `to_representation` method in you serializer with native behaviour and edit `status` action to return only status string (use serializer.instance parameter to get `serializer.instance.status` string and return it in `Response` object.... So in short: leave native `to_representation` method and `return Response(serializer.instance.status)`

Comment: @monio I'll give that a try

Comment: @monio It works perfectly. If you answer the question I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DRF Serializers are designed for django ORM which means that it manipulates django models and primitive dictionaries.

I prefer you to bypass this behaviour directly in status action. You can leave `to_representation` method in you serializer with native behaviour and edit status action to return only status string (use `serializer.instance` parameter to get `serializer.instance.status` string and return it in Response object....

So in short: leave native `to_representation` method and `return Response(serializer.instance.status)`

```
class ReturnLabelTicketStatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer of a return label ticket status."""

    status = serializers.ChoiceField(ReturnLabelTicket.StatusChoice.choices)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        """Take the whole data value as the status."""

        return super().to_internal_value({'status': data})

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """Update the ticket status."""

        instance.status = validated_data.get('status', instance.status)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = ReturnLabelTicket
        fields = ['status']


@action(
    detail=True,
    url_path='status',
    serializer_class=ReturnLabelTicketStatusSerializer
)
def status(self, _request, ticket_id=None):
    """Retrieve the ticket status."""

    ticket = self.get_object()
    serializer = self.get_serializer(ticket)
    return Response(serializer.instance.status)
```